# Have been using React, how to setTimeout or create a Data Carousel like thing which shows new data from a graphql api every couple of mins?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphene-python

querying data from a graphql api, storing it in an array, now have to display it using setTimeout or interval ( imagine a data carousel which changes automatically after a specific time) how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to make sure to clear your interval when your component un-mounts. Otherwise, you'll end up with a nasty set of error messages mentioning how you are setting state on an "unmounted" component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Carousel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            intervalId = 0,
            updatedProps: {}
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;
        let id = setInterval(function() {
            // GRAPHQL => data
            this.setState({updatedProps: data, intervalId: id})
        })
    }
    componentWillUnMount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Carousel 
                    props={this.state.updatedProps}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

`this.setState` is the key to your question

```
setInterval(() => {
    call.to.api(data => {
        this.setState({graphql_data});
        // this will update your ui, as soon as state is set
    })
},miliseconds)
```